# Call a Snowflake procedure from a Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake SQL procedure, which calls a stored procedure, the calling procedure "PROC_TABLE_COUNT" goes in  a for loop dose some processing and calls another procedure "getRowCount" which captures the row count in a specific schema / table.

How to call the procedure and capture the value returned by the procedure.

A sample code for both the procedures is as follows.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TABLE_COUNT()
    returns varchar(20000)
    language sql
    execute as caller
    as
    $$
    declare
      v_err_stmt varchar2;   
      v_sqlerrm varchar2;
      v_src_schema varchar2;
      v_tgt_schema varchar2;
      v_sis_table varchar2;
      v_census_table varchar2;
      v_select_stmt varchar2;
      v_insert_stmt varchar2;
      
      --RCN count
      v_sis_count integer;
      v_census_count integer;
      v_select_RCN_stmt varchar2;
    begin
      v_src_schema := 'SCHEMA_1';
            v_sis_count := getRowCount('SCHEMA_1','TABLE_1');
            v_err_stmt := v_select_RCN_stmt;
            
            -- The row count will be captured and inserted into a table.
       
      
      
      
    end;
    $$;
    
    
    
    
    create or replace procedure  getRowCount(schema_name varchar, table_name varchar)
    returns table(a integer)
    language sql
    as
    $$
      declare
        res RESULTSET;
        query varchar default 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || :schema_name || '.' || :table_name ;
      begin
        res := (execute immediate :query);
        return table (res);
      end;
    $$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of below in procedure code - `PROC_TABLE_COUNT()` -

```
v_sis_count := getRowCount('SCHEMA_1','TABLE_1');
v_err_stmt := v_select_RCN_stmt;
```

Use following -

```
call getRowCount('PUBLIC','TABLE_1');
v_err_stmt := (select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) );
insert into TABLE_1 values (:v_err_stmt); - or whatever table name
```